# Set to All Radio Buttons an id When the Page Loads

Tags: jquery

I have to many radio button groups. I want to set all radio buttons id as parent div's id + itselves values. Because radio buttons are coming from external HTML and in some cases I have to use same buttons a few times in one page. My code example is below and when you select a radio button, its id and form id are setted properly. Is there a way to make it automatically on page load, not based selection?

```
<div id="x1" class="section">
  <form id="" class="myFormClass">
    <input id="" class="myRadio" name="someName-1" value="one">one
    <input id="" class="myRadio" name="someName-1" value="two">two
  </form>
</div>
<div id="x2" class="section">
  <form id="" class="myFormClass">
    <input id="" class="myRadio" name="someName-2" value="three">three
    <input id="" class="myRadio" name="someName-2" value="four">four
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).on('change', "input:radio", function(){
    var parentId = $(this).closest(".section").attr("id");
    var radioValue = this.value;
    var radioName = this.name;
    $(this).parent("form").attr("id", parentId + radioName + "Form") 
    $(this).attr("id", parentId + "-" + radioValue);
  })
</script>
```

And let me ask one more question. When I try to get some elements with common attribute of their, I can get only first element.

```
var iNeedYou = $("input:radio[name='someName-1']").val();
```

returns "one". Is there a way to get all of them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$( document ).ready()` (`$(function()` for short) for running your code when page loaded.
Set your inputs to `type='radio'` if you want radio buttons.

For your extra question: You can use `$('yourSelector').each(function(){` for selecting multiple elements. See in example.

Also see giving the IDs you are saying in the example (parent div id + own value):

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
        var parentId = $(this).closest(".section").attr("id");
        $(this).attr("id", parentId + $(this).val());        
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/4nxhbw8s/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was what I looked.